# divs are overlapping footer

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I am not very good with html and divs are a nightmare.I have to use divs for this page for its flexibility.The image shows the problem.the rightmost div overlaps the footer.I mean it overlaps the table (in which it is placed) and then overlaps the footer.and in this case i am sure the div with the greatest height will overlap the footer.
Just a little background : 
1.I use visual studio
2.the header and footer are set in the masterpage.
[image]

The html is as below :

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
  <table class="unmaintable">
    <tr>
        <td>
           <div class="left" style="background-color:red;width:25%">

               jnzfjnjng<br />
               ngklngjonhjonho<br />
               gjnjbnjonnjjobjhi<br />
               snjnboijihlj</div>
            <div class="left" style="background-color:white;width:56%;">

                vnbkjnbkjiohmoijsiophjpohmp<br />
                smnbkmnkojhklmnkomnpk<br />
                bnmklm kno nkmnkpjhpmnn<br />
                mklm nkjpkhpmf</div>
            <div class="left" style="background-color:#EAEAEA;width:19%;">

                mlmnkopohnmp,n<br />
                n<br />
                n<br />
                n<br />
                nklnmkomnpmkpnmn<br />
                <br />
                <br />
                mkmkmkpm</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </asp:Content>
```

CSS

```
    .unmaintable {
        width: 1000px;
        background-color: #EAEAEA;
        table-layout:fixed;
    }
    .left {
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;

    }
```

I have tried setting the position to absolute/relative but no change

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to use table for layout, but back to the topic...

If the footer element is, for example...

```
<div id="footer"></div>
```

...try to add this CSS code:

```
div#footer { clear: left; }
```

Comment: does nothing.FYI I have a table inside of the footer div.

Comment: Ok, it should be better not to have content inside footer, but try this:
1) Ignore my previous advice;
2) add <div style="clear: left;"></div> after your three <div>s (still inside <td>)
It should work now.